# Css how to make mid windown in chat adjust automatically

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have here a chat window, but i fail to set it up graphically correctly.

Here is a link: http://jsfiddle.net/UD2KL/
It has this structure

```
<nav> </nav>
<div id="chatwindow">
   <div id="message window">
   </div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

- Nav is fixed top, with some info Chatwindow is the Messenger Footer
  contains textbox

So The top is good, it is fixed, the top is also good it is fixed, but the mid where normally the messages should appear here i fail.

If i give it a default value for height like 480, then it is good, i get a scroll bar etc for some size of window it is perfect but when you make window bigger or smaller, so you starting to scale window, the message div is stack to 480 .... if i make it auto height, then i never get scrollbar ...

Anyone can help with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS and HTML is quiet messy, I would've provided you a CSS solution but that may not be the easy way here, by using a wrapper `div` and all stuff, but anyways you are using jQuery so use `.height()`

```
if($(document).height() > $(window).height()) {
    $('#footer').css({'position': 'static'});
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UD2KL/3/)

So the condition here means, `if` `$(document).height()` which is documents `height` is more than `$(window).height()` which is nothing but viewports `height` than set your `#footer` `position` to `static`

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, please ping me if this is not what you were looking for

Comment: hmm, yeas i think it is not what i've ment, because in the window nothing is resized ... My ideas is to have at the top a static toolbar, which stays always at the top , then a place where the messages come, this should be dynamic, i mean when the window is strechted to 800px width then this window should be the same, if it is only 300 then again the width should be adjusted same with the height.  There should be a scrolle bar only in the messaging div and after the message is sent, this should be  scrolled totally down. The footer is static too.

Comment: so i just want, a usual chat window, just like thousands of them ))

Answer (score 0):

As Mr.Alien pointed out, your CSS needs a bit more organization.

But anyhoo, this is my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/eH4nq/

The important bit is the `$window.on('resize', function(e){` part. You basically substract the distance from the container to the top from the distance from the footer to the top.

I've also made some small changes in your CSS. I've added a `height: 100%` on body, reduced a bit the margins and moved the `overflow: auto` on the `#chatwindow`.

Comment: not really working, because i dont know why but the chat window is not scrolled down when message is added and then the messages somehow have the gray background :/ and sometimes when i try to resize window this message div appears behind the static footer